# Range input thumb doesn't align with axis ticks

Tags: html, css, input, sass, input-type-range

The thumb a.k.a. knob in this [`input[type=range]` codepen](http://codepen.io/ryanve/pen/VmZXxj) doesn't line up correctly with the ticks. It seems to be off by a different amount (left or right) depending on the value. Try moving the thumb to see. What CSS can I use to make the thumb line up with the current tick such that it works for all the ticks on the axis?

```css
input.range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  bottom: -10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
input.range:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
input.range::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}
input.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0px 0px 1px black;
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
}
input.range::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0px 0px 1px black;
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input.range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px transparent, 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: indigo;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 0;
}
input.range::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px transparent, 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: indigo;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 0;
}
input.range::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
input.range::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0px 0px 1px black;
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 5px;
}
input.range::-ms-fill-lower,
input.range::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: indigo;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px transparent, 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
.range__tick {
  fill: silver;
}
.range__tick:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(2px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(2px);
  -o-transform: translateX(2px);
  transform: translateX(2px);
}
.range__tick:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-3px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-3px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-3px);
  transform: translateX(-3px);
}
.range__field {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="range__field">
  <input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10">
  <svg role="presentation" width="100%" height="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect class="range__tick" x="0%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
    <rect class="range__tick" x="10%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
    <rect class="range__tick" x="20%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
    <rect class="range__tick" x="30%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
    <rect class="range__tick" x="40%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
    <rect class="range__tick" x="50%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
    <rect class="range__tick" x="60%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
    <rect class="range__tick" x="70%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
    <rect class="range__tick" x="80%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
    <rect class="range__tick" x="90%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
    <rect class="range__tick" x="100%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
  </svg>
  <svg role="presentation" width="100%" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <text class="range__point" x="0%" y="14" text-anchor="start">0</text>
    <text class="range__point" x="10%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">1</text>
    <text class="range__point" x="20%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">2</text>
    <text class="range__point" x="30%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">3</text>
    <text class="range__point" x="40%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">4</text>
    <text class="range__point" x="50%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">5</text>
    <text class="range__point" x="60%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">6</text>
    <text class="range__point" x="70%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">7</text>
    <text class="range__point" x="80%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">8</text>
    <text class="range__point" x="90%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">9</text>
    <text class="range__point" x="100%" y="14" text-anchor="end">10</text>
  </svg>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: you can reposition your counter accordingly so it aligns to the thumb when  it ticks

Comment: follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40431972/770127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not taking into account the width of the thumb in relation to the edge of the track.

One way to solve this is to wrap your two `svg` elements in a `div`, then provide `padding` on both sides equal to *half* of the thumb `width`.

Modify HTML:

```html
<fieldset class="range__field">
    <input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10" />
    <div class="timeline-wrapper">
        <!-- svgs go here -->
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Append to CSS:

```css
.timeline-wrapper {
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

---

```css
.timeline-wrapper {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
input.range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  bottom: -10px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
input.range:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
input.range::-moz-focus-outer {
  border: 0;
}
input.range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0px 0px 1px black;
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
}
input.range::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0px 0px 1px black;
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input.range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px transparent, 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: indigo;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 0;
}
input.range::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px transparent, 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: indigo;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 0;
}
input.range::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
input.range::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black, 0px 0px 1px black;
  border: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 5px;
}
input.range::-ms-fill-lower,
input.range::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: indigo;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px transparent, 0px 0px 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
}
.range__tick {
  fill: silver;
}
.range__tick:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(2px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(2px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(2px);
  -o-transform: translateX(2px);
  transform: translateX(2px);
}
.range__tick:last-child {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-3px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-3px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-3px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-3px);
  transform: translateX(-3px);
}
.range__field {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="range__field">
  <input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="10">
  <div class="timeline-wrapper">
    <svg role="presentation" width="100%" height="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <rect class="range__tick" x="0%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
      <rect class="range__tick" x="10%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
      <rect class="range__tick" x="20%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
      <rect class="range__tick" x="30%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
      <rect class="range__tick" x="40%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
      <rect class="range__tick" x="50%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
      <rect class="range__tick" x="60%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
      <rect class="range__tick" x="70%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
      <rect class="range__tick" x="80%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
      <rect class="range__tick" x="90%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
      <rect class="range__tick" x="100%" y="3" width="1" height="10"></rect>
    </svg>
    <svg role="presentation" width="100%" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <text class="range__point" x="0%" y="14" text-anchor="start">0</text>
      <text class="range__point" x="10%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">1</text>
      <text class="range__point" x="20%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">2</text>
      <text class="range__point" x="30%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">3</text>
      <text class="range__point" x="40%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">4</text>
      <text class="range__point" x="50%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">5</text>
      <text class="range__point" x="60%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">6</text>
      <text class="range__point" x="70%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">7</text>
      <text class="range__point" x="80%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">8</text>
      <text class="range__point" x="90%" y="14" text-anchor="middle">9</text>
      <text class="range__point" x="100%" y="14" text-anchor="end">10</text>
    </svg>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ricky_Ruiz

Comment: Thanx alot! it works very well except the first and the last tick... Is it possible to stick the first one all the way to 0 x position and the last tick to the end?

Comment: Incase anybody needs: you can modify the position the first and last tick with  ```transform: translateX(-8px);```